# Get word length in dict python

Tags: python

Example:

```
 def test_get_word_len_dict():
    text = "May your coffee be strong and your Monday be short"
    the_dict = get_word_len_dict(text)
    print_dict_in_key_order(the_dict)
    print()

    text = 'why does someone believe you when you say there are four billion stars but they have to check when you say the paint is wet'
    the_dict = get_word_len_dict(text)
    print_dict_in_key_order(the_dict)
```

I want to get a dictionary with keys which are
integers and corresponding values which are lists of unique words.The
list of words corresponding to a key contains all the unique words from
the text that have a length equal to the key value. The corresponding
lists of unique words should be in sorted alphabetical order.I don't know how to fix my function

```
def get_len_word_dict():
     new_text = text.split()
     for k,v in new_text.items():
        if len(v) = len(k):
           return k,v
```

expected:

```
 2 : ['be']
 3 : ['May', 'and']
 4 : ['your']
 5 : ['short']
 6 : ['Monday', 'coffee', 'strong']

 2 : ['is', 'to']
 3 : ['are', 'but', 'say', 'the', 'wet', 'why', 'you']
 4 : ['does', 'four', 'have', 'they', 'when']
 5 : ['check', 'paint', 'stars', 'there']
 7 : ['believe', 'billion', 'someone']
```

Comment: For one thing, you have a single equals sign in an if statement. Can you explain what you expect your function to do and why? Right now, even if you changed the `=` to `==`, it would just look for two words with the same length and return them.

Comment: Just use one of the previous answers to this same question, and sort the lists in the dict at the end. There's no need to keep asking the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `defaultdict` of `set`s should do. First, let's define a function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_word_counts(text):
    d = defaultdict(set)

    for word in text.split():
        d[len(word)].add(word)    # observe this bit carefully

    return {k : list(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

The idea is to find the length of each word, and insert it into the list/set that it belongs to. Once you've defined the function, you may call it as you please.

```
text = "May your coffee be strong and your Monday be short"
print(get_word_counts(text))
{2: ['be'], 3: ['and', 'May'], 4: ['your'], 5: ['short'], 6: ['coffee', 'strong', 'Monday']}
```

Comment: Dict function have no effect.

Comment: @Kee Except converting `defaultdict` to a `dict`, it only looks more readable when printing. ;-)

Comment: How to achieve same result with list function and sort the output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.groupby` with `sorted` in order to get similar "lazy" results:

```
a = 'a long list of words in nice'
x = groupby(sorted(a.split(), key=len), len)  # word counts
print(dict((a, list(b)) for a, b in x))
>>> {1: ['a'], 2: ['of', 'in'], 4: ['long', 'list', 'nice'], 5: ['words']}
```

By "lazy" I mean that things would not start actually computing (e.g. if you have a really large string), until you start iterating over it. Be careful with iterators returned by `groupby()` though! That is quite easy to accidentally empty them and then attempt to read second time (and get empty list).

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
>   groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
>   So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list